# Error: ssh: handshake failed: read tcp read: connection reset by peer

Tags: go, tcp, ftp, sftp

I am trying to connect to my vendor's SFTP server using the following golang code.

```
    config := &ssh.ClientConfig{
        User:            user,
        Auth:            []ssh.AuthMethod{ssh.PublicKeys(signer)},
        HostKeyCallback: ssh.InsecureIgnoreHostKey(),
    }
    config.SetDefaults()

    // connect
    conn, err = ssh.Dial(network, address+port, config)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer conn.Close()
```

I am randomly getting ***ssh: handshake failed: read tcp <ip_address_here>:<port_here>-><ftp_ip_address_here>:<ftp_port_here>: read: connection reset by peer*** error in ssh.Dial() method. It works 2 out of 5 times but fails other 3 times. Could this be due to high amount of connection request that FTP server is getting from other clients? And is exponential backoff retry recommended in these cases?

Answer (score 1):

> Could this be due to high amount of connection request that FTP server is getting from other clients?

That is suggested indeed by [`golang/go` issue 20960](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/20960) "net/http: read: connection reset by peer under high load": (got HTTPS, but the limits could apply for SSH connections as well)

> If you get broken network connections, they might be real (a peer really did disconnect), or they might be from hitting kernel limits on one of the sides.

Example:

> I am running 1000 concurrent connections at it eventually hits this also on OSX with file descriptors bumped up from default (256) to 4096.

The [server configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47809316/6309) would matter.

Or:

> I also see this issue under macOS where server and client talk over localhost. I don't know the exact cause of the problem but running `netstat` during high load displays very large number of connections in `TIME_WAIT` state.
>
> Either I exhaust file descriptors or local ports.
> Or both.
>
> I keep seeing connection reset by peer until the number of `TIME_WAIT` connections is about 7k. If I let the test run even further, I eventually get `connect: can't assign requested address` error which suggests that I exhausted local ports.
> The number of TIME_WAIT connections is at 15k.
>
> For my project that's not needed and I could solve the problem by limiting number of concurrent connections. Solving the problem in my code by limiting number of goroutines seemed arbitrary and still occasionally failed.
> Limiting `MaxConnsPerHost` in http transport did the trick and problem went away completely.